# Ionic local storage not getting the data

Tags: angular, ionic3, ionic-storage

I am trying to get the token that I stored using the ionic storage and store it in a global variable `public token = ''`. But every time I access it using `this.token` the value doesn't change.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

const TOKEN_KEY = 'access_token';

@Injectable()
export class ContactProvider {

  public url = 'myapi-link';
  public token = '';


  constructor(
    private storage: Storage,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {

  }

  loadToken(){

    this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY).then((token)=>{
      this.token = token;
      console.log(this.token);
    });

  }

  setHeaders(default_content_type = 'application/json'){

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', default_content_type)
    .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token)
    return headers;

  }

  getData(type){

    this.loadToken();
    let headers = this.setHeaders();
    return this.http.get(this.url + type, {headers: headers});

  }

}
```

when calling the `this.setHeaders()`, the `this.token` does not change.

Answer (score 1):

Like Others have pointed out, you need to understand how promises work.
Here is something how: 
1: LoadToken needs to return a promise:

```
loadToken(){
    return this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY);
}
```

Note the **return** key word which will return the promise returned by storage.get()

2: consume that promise and wait for it to complete before you carry on:

```
async getData(type){
    this.token = await this.loadToken();
    let headers = this.setHeaders();
    return this.http.get(this.url + type, {headers: headers});
}
```

Note the **async** key word in front of the getData method name which indicates you will be waiting for promises to complete within it.
then the **await** key word which will make sure the rest of the code after it will only execute when the promise resolves.

Since a promise can also be rejected, you need to do the following :

```
async getData(type){
  try {
    this.token = await this.loadToken();
    let headers = this.setHeaders();
    return this.http.get(this.url + type, {headers: headers});
  } catch (error) {
     //Handle your error here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the setHeaders within the loadToken as it returns the data asynchronously,

```
loadToken(){
    this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY).then((token)=>{
      this.token = token;
      console.log(this.token);
      this.headers = this.setHeaders();
    });
}
```

Comment: is there a way to wait for the token to totally load it from the storage?

Comment: use loadToken().then

Comment: You'll need to return a promise from `loadToken()` for @Sajeetharan's suggestion above